# Visual height inconsistency

Tags: html, css, height, width

I'm new to web development and am VERY lost on a project. I'm trying to do a simple film portofolio for a friend of mine, and I'm quite lost on a visual resizing problem. I'm trying to make this very simple landing page, where the top video is taking 67% of the screen, and four others at the bottom. The example my friend gave me looks like this : https://www.iconoclast.tv/uk/gus-van-sant

I don't get how they manage to have the top video stay stuck at 67% of height when resizing on the width axis. Mine looks perfectly fine (see images below), but as soon as I'm resizing a bit to much on the horizontal axis it begins to shrink, which is very weird because it's contained within a class of 100% height and weight (inside a 67% viewport height). I would like the video to stay stuck at the top and bottom of that 67% portion.

[Looks fine !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quLgU.jpg)

[Looks awful ! Should also take a third of the vertical height... but doesnt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE8N3.png)

Here is my html (i borrowed a css stylesheet where everything is pretty straightforward but tell me if anything looks weird or not comprehensible to you).

```
<html land="en" class="no-touch">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>name here</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Director based in Paris.">
    <meta name="twitter:card" value="Director based in Paris.">
    <meta property="og:title" content="name here"> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="Director based in Paris.">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body class="bgc-black fc-white ttu">
    <div id="preload">
        <span class="ff-rb">XYZ</span>
        <span class="ff-rr">XYZ</span>
    </div>
    <div id="root">
    
        <div class="ff-rb fs2 ls25">
            <div class="psf t0 l0 w100 h100 bgc-black z2 nav-curtain op0 pen"></div>

        <div class="bgc-black">
            <div class="psf t0 w100 z1 x xdc xac director-title nav-hide" style="transform: translateY(-24px);">
                <h1 class="fs4 fwb lh1">NAME HERE</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="x xw xac">
                <div class="psr oh md-s1 s1 vh67 md-vh75" data-index="0">
                    <div class="psa op100" style="top:0px; width:100%; height:100%">
                        <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/863989491?muted=1&autoplay=1&dnt=1&loop=1&transparent=0&background=1&app_id=122963" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; loop; picture-in-picture" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="MOUTY_HOVER"></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>

                


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your insights on this, i'm quite lost honestly !!

I was expecting some kind of result where the video doesnt resize vertically nor horizontally, just like this example :

[Example from friend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFs5D.jpg)